# SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism

Tags: java

I need to fix the problem of

`SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism`

Following up on [OpenJDK 11 error "Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58182231/openjdk-11-error-can-not-initialize-cryptographic-mechanism), as its answer is unable to solve my problem

> inspecting  `java.security.properties` from within running JVM:
>
> ```
>     System.getProperty("java.security.properties");
> ```
>
> It should be present and pointing at a file. Inspect that file and make sure it has the following property `crypto.policy=unlimited` and the folder called **unlimited** is available from where the policy file is.

However, I got `null` output for both java under Windows and Linux.

The above answer said that

it is `<jre_home>/conf/security/policy/`

and my situation is that I don't have `jre` however I do have the `/conf/security/policy/` directory under `java_home`, for both java under Windows and Linux.

```
 Directory of C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-18.0.1.1\conf\security\policy

04/25/2022  04:59 PM    <DIR>          .
04/25/2022  04:59 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/25/2022  04:59 PM    <DIR>          limited
04/25/2022  04:59 PM             2,390 README.txt
04/25/2022  04:59 PM    <DIR>          unlimited
               1 File(s)          2,390 bytes
```

```
$ ls -l /home/foo/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.3-oracle/conf/security/policy
total 4
-rw-r----- 1 foo foo 2390 2022-03-09 17:40 READfoo.txt
drwxrwx--x 1 foo foo 4096 2022-06-03 12:45 limited
drwxrwx--x 1 foo foo 4096 2022-06-03 12:45 unlimited
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Cryptographic Strength Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-cryptography-architecture-jca-reference-guide.html#GUID-EFA5AC2D-644E-4CD9-8523-C6D3936D5FB1) ...and build the path with `$JAVA_HOME`.

On Linux the default paths are:

- JDK8: `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`
- JDK11: `$JAVA_HOME/conf/security`
- JDK14: `$JAVA_HOME/conf/security`, mostly sym-linked to `/etc/java-14-openjdk/security`.

"Jurisdiction Policy File" `java.security` should have `crypto.policy = unlimited` set from JDK9 onwards; policies can be found `$JAVA_HOME/conf/security/unlimited/default_US_export.policy`.

Comment: So my files are at the proper place, but why the output of `System.getProperty("java.security.properties")` is `null` for both java under Windows and Linux?

Comment: That other answer runs with `java -D...` ...and this sets the property. Why not `System.getProperty("java.home")`??

Comment: I need to fix "Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism" which requires System.getProperty("java.security.properties") _"be present and pointing at a file. "_. Printing java.home won't help. How to let System.getProperty("java.security.properties") pointing to the proper file?

Comment: I downgraded my Java from V18 to V11 and the "Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism" just gone.